# Find if the element contains x but not y (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, text, find, match, contain

```
<div>
  <p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p>
  <p><a href="#">link</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">link</a> some text</p>
  <p><a href="#">link</a></p>
</div>
```

I want to find (and addClass to) the `<p>` tags that DO NOT contain text, directly inside itself or its children.

Comment: The selector you describe wouldn't select any of the paragraphs above, is that correct?

Comment: It would select the ones with the link only and NOT the ones that contain "some text"

Comment: But the children contain text and you explicitly said "tags that DO NOT contain text, directly inside itself or its children."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine, I did have to empty the text out of one of your paragraphs to test:

```
var $eles = $('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length == 0;
});
$eles.addClass("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose You have an error in the problem description, as the a tag always contains text in the example.

As far as I know there is no standard selector allowing to check if there is a direct content, but You could try this:

```
$('p').each(function(){
 var p = $(this).clone();
 p.children().remove();
 if(p.text().length){
   $(this).addClass('gotcha');
  }
});
```

Should work if You wish to check only the paragraph insides.